# how to implement this flow of activities - many going through one MainCheckerActivity -> back or SettingsActivity?

Tags: android, workflow, android-activity

I have one central **MainCheckerActivity** which checks if all the settings are OK. This **MainCheckerActivity** is being called by many activities A,B,C,..

If the **MainCheckerActivity** finds that some settings are missing it shows a dialog and (currently) finishes so the flow returns to the calling activity A,B,C...

Then the user has to manually navigate to the SettingsActivity from A,B,C...

**So basically now:**

```
A -> MainCheckerActivity -> shows the dialog -> finishes MainCheckerActivity -> A -> SettingsActivity
```

**How would I implement a logic flow which is more convenient for the user like this:**

```
A -> MainCheckerActivity -> shows the dialog -> finishes MainCheckerActivity -> SettingsActivity -> A
```

Many thanks!

Comment: your question is going to receive a whole lot less attention if you forget to tag it under `android`. thank you for using `android-activity` instead of `activity` though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start the MainCheckerActivity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, then it will not be kept in the history stack of the task. If MainCheckerActivity launches the SettingsActivity, when the user clicks "back" in the SettingsActivity he will return to the activity that started MainCheckerActivity (ie: either A, B, or C from your description).

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps application does something similar. If you forget to turn on GPS satellites, it will pop up a dialog asking something like, "do you want to turn on GPS satellites and/or wifi to improve the accuracy of your location?". The workflow is as follows:

1. You launch Google Maps `MainActivity` (and search for "my location").
2. The app realizes that you have forgotten to turn on GPS satellites and/or wifi internet. A dialog pops up asking whether or not you would like to tweak the settings. The options are "skip" (negative button) and "settings" (positive button). There is also a "do this by default"... you might consider adding something like this in case your setting-requirements begin pissing off users. :)
3. (a) If "skip" is clicked, dismiss the dialog and you are still in `MainActivity`.

   (b) If "settings"  is clicked, the `SettingsActivity` is launched. You make changes to the settings. Then when you are finished, you click "back", the changes are saved, and you return to the `MainActivity`.

So in other words, it seems like the best idea would be to merge the `MainCheckerActivity` with activities `A`, `B`, and `C`. Killing off an unnecessary activity almost always results in a better user experience. :)

Comment: How can I "merge the MainCheckerActivity" with activities" ? MainCheckerActivity is a separate activity which decides to call settings or not. Merging it with A,B,C.. means that its code would have to be multiplied for each of these activities?

Comment: You could still re-use the code by keeping it in a separate class... you don't have to devote an entirely separate screen for it, that's all i'm saying.